# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\log 2$

Tags: definite-integrals

Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\, dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\log 2$
 I have tried to sole the problem, but failed. Any one can help me to sole the problems.

Here, I have tried to solve this using integration by parts :
Let $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\, dx$.  Then
$I=\left[ \tan^{-1}x\,\log(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x}\, dx$

How can I integrate the second term?

Comment: The function you are integrating has an indefinite integral which has no closed form, so the method you are trying to apply will probably not work. Try using some of the tricks for calculating improper integrals...